# Playing a video stored in server in android WebView

Tags: javascript, php, android, iframe, webview

This is the thing.

I have designed a web page and stored it in an apache server. The web page uses php to load an html  with directories of images, audio and video files. Then, when selecting a directory, a php section also displays thumbnails form files contained in selected directory. The thumbnails are displayed in an  to load everything in the same page.

I load the page in a web browser and works fine. After displaying the thumbnails, I can select any of them, it doesn matter if is an image and audio or a video. I can see normal size of image, I can listen the audio and I can see the video playing in the same iframe (which is what I want), depending on what I have selected.

On Android app:

Then, i have created an android app using only WebView to load the page in the app. Page is loaded perfectly. I can select an image and see the original size of image in the same iframe. But, audio files and video files are not played on the iframe, not even played in a different page. I want them to be played on the same iframe. Everything is loaded in the WebView only.

I don know if this could be done correctly like this.

WebView code is here:

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings(); 
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);               
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    // Load page in apache server.
    myWebView.loadUrl(url:"defined previously");
```

If anyone could be helpful that would be much appreciated.
Thanks.